# Color cycles for charts

Tags: bokeh

I've been trying to create a plot with many (~1000s) of boxplots using Bokeh (v0.8.1). I noticed that whenever I try to use the bokeh.charts.BoxPlot function I hit an error with plots with more than 6 boxplots.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.charts import BoxPlot
test = {}
for i in range(0,7):
    test[str(i)] = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
plot = BoxPlot(test)
show(plot)
```

Stacktrace:

```
ipython-input-321-6a3614410bf5> in <module>()
      4 for i in range(0,7):
      5     test[str(i)] = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
----> 6 plot = BoxPlot(test)
      7 show(plot)
/opt/pkg/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder/boxplot_builder.pyc in BoxPlot(values, marker, outliers, xscale, yscale, xgrid, ygrid, **kw)
     79     return create_and_build(
     80         BoxPlotBuilder, values, marker=marker, outliers=outliers,
---> 81         xscale=xscale, yscale=yscale, xgrid=xgrid, ygrid=ygrid, **kw
     82     )
     83 

/opt/pkg/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/_builder.pyc in create_and_build(builder_class, values, **kws)
     38     chart_kws = { k:v for k,v in kws.items() if k not in builder_props}
     39     chart = Chart(**chart_kws)
---> 40     chart.add_builder(builder)
     41 
     42     return chart

/opt/pkg/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/_chart.pyc in add_builder(self, builder)
    113     def add_builder(self, builder):
    114         self._builders.append(builder)
--> 115         builder.create(self)
    116 
    117         # Add tools if supposed to

/opt/pkg/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/_builder.pyc in create(self, chart)
    161     def create(self, chart=None):
    162         self._adapt_values()
--> 163         self._process_data()
    164         self._set_sources()
    165         renderers = self._yield_renderers()

/opt/pkg/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder/boxplot_builder.pyc in _process_data(self)
    185                 out_x.append(level)
    186                 out_y.append(o)
--> 187                 out_color.append(self.palette[i])
    188 
    189         # Store

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It appears that whatever predefined color list for the BoxPlot function has run out of colors for new boxplots.

Is there a way to either define a new color list (ideally, a cycle that will simply repeat colors if it runs out) or disable coloring entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Cycle colors implementation to repeat colors on bokeh.charts have been added in recent versions (IIRC 0.8). It seems like it's a bug. Stack Overflow is really not the best place for such discussion and to track issues.

I've opened an issue related to the cycle_colors/palette bug on charts that also contains a quick way you can use to bypass the problem. You can see it [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2158). Basically you can explicitly build and pass you own big enough palette. If you'd like to help or provide other feedbacks please use the related GH issue mostly because it's easier for us to track.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should have put the version of Bokeh I was using in my question, so apologies for that. I'm on 0.8.1 right now, upgraded to 0.8.2 just to be sure, which caused me to encounter a different error upon trying to import bokeh.charts. I will report the new bug on github and once that's resolved come back to this to see if the new version fixes this issue.

Comment: The import error I was facing had something to do with me upgrading from 0.8.1->0.8.2. On a fresh install of Bokeh, this error still exists in 0.8.2, so I posted this particular problem to github.

Comment: @schultzmattd I've updated the answer with better details and a link to the related GH issue.